# Updates to the linux kernel 2.6.22 custom for freescale i.MX27

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, nxp-microcontroller

I wonder if anyone has information on updates
for the linux kernel 2.6.22 custom for freescale i.MX27 ?

I searched and searched NXP/freescale with no success...

What I have is a legacy product using such heavily customised kernel,
such kernel cannot be updated simply with the main stream linux.

On github you find a repo with recent linux kernels under "Freescale":
any info on those too will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: no, it is not off topic because it belongs to embedded linux

Comment: not related to programming at all, man.

Comment: Mainline linux support for the i.mx27 is actually great. Porting it to your board is probably doable. The recent kernels from Freescale are focusing on i.mx6 and i.mx7 support so this is not something that will help you.

Comment: 1) The question as is, it is for embedded developers who had the problem to patch the heavily customised freescale kernel, so only embedded dev's will have expertise on this, not the unix gurus 2) I'm working on a legacy product and I cannot switch to mainline linux kernel, but only patch this old freescale heavily customised version for the i.mx27 board.